# How to print ZPL label stored after Feed Button Clicked - TLP 2824 plus

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I create label in Zebra Designer. When I print it from Designer printer print it correct - super.
Next I sended my work into the printer. And when I'm checking files in printer TEST.ZPL and TEST001.GRF, TEST002.GRF are correctly downloaded on printer. I send them into E: Onboard flash but also to R: RAM

Now I want to configure my printer that after remove usb conection with my PC printer will print TEST.ZPL label form memory after pressed green button (Feed button)

Currently it prints clear label.

I'll be greatefull for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish what you are trying to do:

1. Add a Zebra KDU or KDU Plus http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/accessories/keyboards.html The KDU will allow an operator to recall a format stored on the printer.  You have to purchase a KDU.
2. To program the Feed button you will need to create a program that runs on the printer using Zebra BASIC Interpreter (ZBI - http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/adapt-software/zebra-basic-interpreter2.html )  This way is more complex and you need to purchase $99 ZBI License to unlock the ZBI functionality on the printer, but with the right program you can get the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: When you download the ZBI samples, looks for "front_panel_control.zbi" it will show you how to register the key press for the Feed key.  You can then have a subroutine fire to print the label.